# Ember-cli filtering model by name, with html select options

Tags: ember.js

Im getting started with emberjs, and I have connected my ember app to an API, and my models working fine.
I can display the model in my template, but how can I filter them?
Example, this is my model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  placeofdamage: DS.attr('string'),
  ees: DS.attr(),
  type: DS.belongsTo('type'),
  brand: DS.belongsTo('brand')
});
```

How can I display ex. only BMW? With this method:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selectBrand">
  {{#each model.brands as |brand|}}
    <option>{{brand.name}}</option>
   {{/each}}
 </select>
```

Thank you for any further reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main approach. You can ask server to filter them for you or filter it yourself. The later will obviously not scale well for large amount of records.

To filter it yourself you can use addon like [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#filter-by) it will make your life a bit easier or you can create computed property for it yourself.

To let it filter your api you will have to use [query](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_query) on store.

If you want allow users to toggle this filter you can wire it up yourself or use [query-params](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/routing/query-params/). I would recommend you to read this one.

Comment: Thanks, I used the composable helpers, with ember power select, and query params.

Answer (score 0):

My answers is specific to your example. You can install `ember-truth-helpers` addon simply you can put eq check.

```
{{#each model.brands as |brand|}}
  {{#if (eq brand.name "BMW") }}
    <option>{{brand.name}}</option> 
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Or create computed property and filter the brand using `filterBy`,

```
onlyBMWBrand: Ember.computed('model.brands', function(){
 return this.get('model.brands').filterBy('name','BMW');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Could write an is-equal helper by

```
ember generate helper is-equal
```

Content for helpers/is-equal.js

```
import Ember from "ember";

export function checkEquality([leftSide, rightSide]) {
    return leftSide === rightSide;
}

export default Ember.Helper.helper(checkEquality);
```

In template

```
{{#each cars as |car|}}
   {{#if (is-equal car.brand "BMW")}}
       <img src={{bmwLogo}} />
   {{else if (is-equal car.brand "Volvo")}}
       <img src={{volvoLogo}} />
   {{else}}
        No match.
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Shouldnt really use this approach when you have hundreds of car records. Let the backend do the job.